# remove .append() added elements only

Tags: jquery

I'm using .append() to attach a list of images but I'd like to be able to remove the added elements in-order return to the starting state

```
$.each(get_images, function(i,img){
 $('#container ul').append('<li><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="'+img+'"/></a></li>');   
});
```

Comment: and where is your remove function implementation ?

Comment: can you not just do `$('.thumbnail').remove()`?

Comment: I think he basically wants to store the appended images somewhere, so he can later remove exactly these..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$.each(get_images, function(i,img){ $('#container ul').append('<li class="removeMe"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="'+img+'"/></a></li>'); });`

Then you just have to do `$('.removeMe').remove();`
And all the appended are gone!
OR
one-by-one from last to first

> $('.removeMe:last').remove();

:)

Comment: @Wanting how come this is working but my code isn't? it's the exact same thing

Comment: @koala_dev maybe because the change to his code is smaller/simpler and that makes it easier to understand... idk.

Answer (score 5):

Add a class to each item you append, then use that class to reference the added elements

```
 $('#container ul').append('<li class="appended"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="'+img+'"/></a></li>');
```

To remove all:

```
$('#container ul li.appended').remove();
```

Or to remove them in order:

```
$('#container ul li.appended:last').remove();
```

Comment: Can you give more details? explain exactly what you want to happen and what is happening now